# Orchard 1.6 HQL - OR predicate across joined tables?

Tags: hql, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

I'm trying to join a `JobPart` to both a `TitlePartRecord` and a `BodyPartRecord`, and perform a logical `OR` for text contained in either the Title or Body parts.

My first attempt was to use the `ContentManager` to Join the parts, however, I cannot perform an `OR`, only an `AND`, as a `WHERE` clause is only applied to the `Join` immediately above:

```
        var q = _orchardServices.ContentManager.Query<JobPart>()
                .Join<TitlePartRecord>()
                .Where(r => r.Title.Contains(filter.FreeText))
                .Join<BodyPartRecord>()
                .Where(r => r.Text.Contains(filter.FreeText))
                .List();
```

So the above will return JobParts where the search term is in both the Body and Title parts, just not in either.

My next attempt was to use the HqlQuery, where someone is having the same issue described [here](http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/389730):

```
        var q = _orchardServices.ContentManager.HqlQuery()
                .ForPart<JobPart>()
                .Join(x => x.ContentPartRecord<TitlePartRecord>())
                .Join(x => x.ContentPartRecord<BodyPartRecord>())
                .Where(alias => alias.ContentPartRecord<TitlePartRecord>(),
                        factory => factory.Or(
                            lhs => lhs.InsensitiveLike("Title", filter.FreeText, HqlMatchMode.Anywhere),
                            rhs => rhs.InsensitiveLike("Text", filter.FreeText, HqlMatchMode.Anywhere)));
```

However, this fails as the OR is being applied to the `TitlePart`, and "Text" is not a property of the `TitlePart`, rather the `BodyPart`.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction to perform an `OR` across the join?  Sure I'm missing something small.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - this is not possible with "OR", only "AND"....

Comment: that is a shame then.